# Vagrant multi-machine - connection between machines

Tags: php, elasticsearch, vagrant

I have simple vagrant multi-machine config:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant/ubuntu-16.04/provision.sh"
  config.vm.synced_folder "ed", "/var/www/html"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 2
  end
  config.vm.define "node1", primary: true do |node|
    node.vm.hostname = 'node1'
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.101"
    node.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 10122, id: "ssh"
    node.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
  end
  config.vm.define "node2" do |node|
    node.vm.hostname = "node2"
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.102"
    node.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 10123, id: "ssh"
    node.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
  end
end
```

On `node1` I have php and on `node2` I have elasticsearch.

When I run `curl localhost:9200` from `vagrant@node2` it works,

but when I try run `curl 192.168.56.102:9200` from `vagrant@node1` it won't work, I get error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.56.102 port 9200: Connection refused
```

Comment: is the port 9200 opened in the firewall of 192.168.56.102?

Comment: @NangSaigon How can I check it?

Comment: @NangSaigon I ran `netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep 9200` and received `tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      -`
`tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      -`

Comment: I think to do a quick test, you can simply turn off the firewall: sudo ufw disable and then use the Curl command again

Comment: In addition, I hope you did setup the private network succesffuly, have you tried to ping from node 1 to node2?

Comment: @NangSaigon `sudo ufw disable` didn't help. I can ping node1 from node2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, elasticsearch listening on localhost. So, It will be accessible from local only. see your output:

```
netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep 9200

tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:9200 :::* LISTEN - tcp6 0 0 ::1:9200 :::* LISTEN
```

You have to bind `elasticsearch` port to your IP address to access from outside.

Open your `elasticsearch.yml` and add IP address to `network.host` option.

```
network.host: "192.168.56.102"
```

After that restart `elasticsearch` service.

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Comment: yes, you can ask new question . if i will not be able to help then someone who know more about that will help you. don't delete this question bcoz this might help others. also add there listening port detail that will be more helpful.